# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Cross Validated's [fifth moderator election](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Sycorax] [image: kjetil b halvorsen]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Peter Flom who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5664538390167552/0).

Comment: Congratulations to Sycorax & Kjetil.

Comment: Many thanks to @Peter Flom for his extensive and diligent service over 7 years as a moderator, always moderate, sensible and sensitive.

Comment: Congratulations to @Sycorax and @kjetilbhalvorsen!